# Log Into an App Container with cloud foundry SSH via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloud-foundry

I am trying to SSH into an app running on Cloud Foundry as explained in the official documentation https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html.
I would like to do this via a Jenkins pipeline.
Below the Jenkins file

```sh
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        CF_ORGANIZATION = "organization"
        CF_SPACE = "test"
    }

    stage('login to my app') {
            steps {
                    sh "cf login -a <Api end point> -u ${CF_USER} -p ${CF_PASS}"
                    sh "cf target -o ${CF_ORGANIZATION} -s ${CF_SPACE}"
                    sh "cf ssh myapp"
                    sh "touch testfile.txt"
                }
        
            }
 }
```

The `cf login` and `cf target` work, but the `cf ssh myapp` doesn't go through. I don't have a failure message but if I try do to something on the remote machine (such as write a file via `touch testfile.txt`) it doesn't do anything. Do you know if this is the right approach or the cf cli doesn't work in this case?

Comment: You might try `cf ssh myapp -c 'touch testfile.txt'`. That'll run the command locally. You could have it run a script too, but you'd have to have the script available remotely. That might require copying it to the app container first, if it doesn't exist there. This is similar to `ssh user@host command`, but with `cf ssh` you need the `-c` argument.

Comment: Thanks, that seems working. But when I run the command like this, I get the error "Incorrect Usage. Requires APP_NAME as argument",as shell cannot recognize the APP NAME after ssh. Should the APP NAME inside quotes or similar?

Comment: `But when I run the command like this` -> How? I don't see an example referenced? In some cases, the cf cli does care about the order of arguments. I believe `cf ssh <app-name> -c 'cmd'` should be OK, but you can look at `cf ssh -h` and confirm exactly.